# Update a href ID using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

On a page I have songs playing in a small audio player and the song change every 1-2 minutes or when I want them to(like a radio).
Every song can be voted by users this way:

```
<span class='up'><a href="" class="vote" id="<?php echo $mes_id; ?>" name="up"><img src="up.png" alt="Down" /></a></span><br />
```

For upvote button, `<div class="totalvotes"></div>` for total votes and

```
<span class='down'><a href="" class="vote" id="<?php echo $mes_id; ?>" name="down"><img src="down.png" alt="Down" /></a></span>
```

for downvote button.

Everything is working well but the page obviously will refresh when I click on one of the buttons to vote.
The `id="<?php echo $mes_id; ?>"` from `a` element is what I need to be updated every 1-2 seconds because it gets the id of the current song playing.

For the totalvotes the solution was using:

```
function refresh_div() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:'totalvotes.php',
            type:'POST',
            success:function(totalvotes) {
                jQuery(".totalvotes").html(totalvotes);
            }

        });

    }



    t = setInterval(refresh_div,1000);
```

It was easy because I created a div with a class and specified the class in the function. But I have no ideea how can I specify the ID of a "a" to be updated every second.

Comment: `$(element).attr('href', 'new_href_here');`

Comment: send all the ID's to server as data, return json that includes id's and counts. Simple loop over the response to update all the votes in the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `.attr()` to change any attribute on a HTML element.

```
function updateLink() {
    // get id of current song.
    // newValue is that id. 
    $("a").attr('id',newValue);

}

setInterval(updateLink,1000);
```

Comment: that sets every id for all`<a>` tags in the page to the same id. Makes no sense and creates invalid page since ID's can't be repeated

Comment: I know, it's not an specific solution, but it gives an idea of how to achieve it.

Comment: The solution is general as charlietfl said. So can i specify which `a`'s element ID to update?

Comment: Yes. jQuery works with CSS selectors. For example, if you want to change the `a` inside the `span` with the `up` class, you would use `$('span.up>a').attr('id',newValue)`

Answer (score 0):

I would rather place that link in a div and update that div with a new link using ajax

Comment: I use class "vote" and id's "up" and "down" to update the totalvotes value when I click on one of the buttons. How could I do that without messing the other functions?

Answer (score 0):

get the ID of the playing song with Ajax
just get the reference to anchor element globally in page load with

```
var anchor = $("#<?php echo $mes_id; ?>");
```

and set

```
$(anchor).attr("id", idReturnedFromAjaxCall);
$(anchor).attr("href", theUrlIBuilded);
```